# Regex which validate for all caps

Tags: php, regex

I want a regular expression in PHP which will check for all caps the string.

If the given string contains all capital letters irrespective of numbers and other characters then it should match them.

Comment: Is this ASCII text or UTF-8 text?

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to match other characters too, look for lowercase letters instead of uppercase letters. If found, return false. (Or use [tdammers' suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223935/regex-which-validate-for-all-caps/4223962#4223962) of a negative character class.)

```
return !preg_match('/[a-z]/', $str);
```

You can also skip regex and just compare `strtoupper($str)` with the original string, this leaves digits and symbols intact:

```
return strtoupper($str) == $str;
```

Both don't account for multi-byte strings though; for that, you could try adding a `u` modifier to the regex and using `mb_strtoupper()` respectively (I've not tested either — could someone more experienced with Unicode verify this?).

Answer (score 3):

```
if (preg_match('/^[^\p{Ll}]*$/u', $subject)) {
    # String doesn't contain any lowercase characters
} else {
    # String contains at least one lowercase characters
}
```

`\p{Ll}` matches a Unicode lowercase letter; `[^\p{Ll}]` therefore matches any character that is not a lowercase letter.

Comment: Good job dealing with Unicode properties, Tim, instead of hardcoding `[a-z]` like the rest of them did.

Comment: @tchrist: Well, you know who has been reminding me of this recently :)

Comment: it’s because at work I have to deal with other people’s programming errors related to Unicode several times a week on average, usually regexes or I/O encodings. The burnt child fears fire.

Comment: +1, I really have to buck up with my Unicode. @Daniel Standage: I know that feeling.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
'/^[^a-z]*$/'
```

The trick is to use an exclusive character class: this one matches all characters that are not lower-case letters. Note that accented letters aren't checked.